# Why isn't upper bound unique?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

If there is an upper bound $a$ of a set $A$, and an upper bound $b$ of the set $A$ and $b>a$, why doesn't that mean that only $b$ is the upper bound of the set since it's "more upper" than $a$?

Comment: If there were a concept of "more upper" then no subsets of $\mathbb R$ would have an upper bound at all (any bounded set has an upper bound, then choose one plus that to get a "more upper," hence it doesn't exist). Upper bounds need not be unique, and in most cases you'll have infinitely many, but the *least upper bound* (sup) is unique. You may wish to prove that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be confused with the terms *UPPER BOUND* and *LEAST UPPER BOUND*.

For more information on the latter term, refer to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property).

Answer (score 0):

An upper bound of a set $A$, by definition, is simply

> An element that is larger than (or equal to) all elements of $A$.

So, for example, if $A=[0,1]$, then $2$ is an upper bound of $A$, because we can say that $2$ is larger or equal to all elements of $[0,1]$. Also, $3$ is an upper bound of $A$, and so is $4$ and several other numbers.

By your logic, since for any $a$ which is an upper bound of $A=[0,1]$, the number $b=a+1$ is also an upper bound for $A$, then $A$ has no upper bound because no number us "more upper" than all other numbers.

Comment: Thanks! I get the idea of upper bound now, but what is it good for? I understand that least upper bound is useful, but what good does it do to know other upper bounds?

Comment: @user265554 There are sets with no least upper bound, but still bounded. Furthermore, in $\mathbb R$, a set has a least upper bound if and only if it has an upper bound. Therefore, to prove it has a least upper bound, all you need to do is find **some** upper bound.

Comment: Ooooh okay. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Following the previous answers also remember "If any non empty  set of real numbers has an upper bound it necessarily has a least upper bound in real numbers
"

Comment: Not true. Consider $\{x \mid x^2 < 2\}$ as a subset of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I guess I missed a detail @Nitin I guess it is fine now